# Spur spawn not launching all the process to remote machine

Tags: python, ssh, spawn

I am launching around 20 processes on a remote machine using spur(spawn). But sometimes it will launch all and sometimes it will launch 1 or 2 out of 20.

Is there a way to know why it's not launching? or any other way of launching scripts together?

Note: I need to return after launching, I don't have to wait for the process to finish on the remote machine.

```
def spur_spawn(command,host,user,pwd,log):
        try:
                print "Command",command
                log.info("Command used on host : %s - > %s",host,command)
                if host == "local":

                        shell = spur.LocalShell()
                        result = shell.spawn(["sh", "-c", command],store_pid=True)

                else:
                        shell = spur.SshShell(hostname=host, username=user, password=pwd,shell_type=spur.ssh.ShellTypes.minimal,missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
                        result = shell.spawn(["sh", "-c", command],allow_error=True)
                return result
        except Exception as e:
                import traceback
                log.error("Not able to launch job {} -> {}".format(e,host))
                s = traceback.format_exc()
                serr = "> stderr:\n%s\n" % (s)
                print serr
                logging.error("{}  -> {}".format(e,host))
                return 1,"",e
```

Comment: As you so not say how you launch the processes, I cannot guess what could cause some processes not to execute...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I added my code. Please have a look and give me some suggestion

Comment: I am not getting anything in except block. So not able to debug why its not launching my process on remote machine

Comment: What does `result` contain for failed commands?

Comment: It's not failed, It didn't launch anything. For the command that got launched and for those which haven't got launched, the output is same: <spur.ssh.SshProcess object at 0x7f089cd36390>

Comment: At least in a debugging phase you should try to use `wait_for_result()` on what you called `result` to wait for end of execution and control the `return_code` and optionally `output` and `stderr_output`.